# map columns in Pentaho spoon

Tags: pentaho

I have input.csv file with 3 columns viz, name,age,address. And, I have an output.csv file with 5 columns viz, Person name,Person age,Person address,Person salary,Person pass criteria.

I need to map my input.csv to output.csv. Please help me out with this. I tried `Select values` step, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 4 steps.

[image]

1) Using `CSV file input` step you can get the name,age,address fields 

 2) Using `Select values` step you can rename name,age,address fields to Person name,Person age,Person address. 

 3) Using `Add constants` step you can add the additional fields, Person salary,Person pass criteria. 

 4) Using `Text file output` step you can output to a csv file. Here as the extension, type `csv` and separator as `,`.

Comment: is it possible to have another approach? ,. what if there are more fields in input.csv and few fields in output.csv ? also, what if there are many files to be mapped to the same output.csv

Comment: Will the number of columns/names of the columns differ from file to file? If they are fixed for a ktr run then, you can always decide what to write to output using `Select values` step and add the new fields to `Add constants` step.

Comment: yes. columns/names differ.

Eg,
file1 --> name,age
file2 --> Name,Ag,Sal
file3 --> (here in this file, fields are coming in 2nd row)
check details
Nm,Age,Salary,Addree


now say my output file has only Name,Addess...  How can we approach this issue?